# How i can disable web preview?

Tags: bots, botframework, skype

In skype, when i send message that contains some url and have setting

`'textformat' => 'markdown'`

skype by default create web preview. How i can handle that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go the Tools > Options > IM & SMS > IM appearence and then you can uncheck the "Show link previews" option.

[image]